# Get Hibernate Entity column value instead of associated object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an Hibernate Entity that has a relationship with another entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "main_entity")
public class MainEntity {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToOne
    SecondaryEntity secondaryEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "secondary_entity")
public class SecondaryEntity {
    @Id
    Long id;
}
```

In the table `main_entity` I have a column `secondary_entity_id` that contains the ID of the corresponding enity used in the relationship.

Sometime a `MainEntity` can have an ID in the `secondary_entity_id` column, but no entity assocaited in the `secondary_entity` table.

In this case, I'd like to retrieve the actual value in the column (the ID) and not the entity that doesn't exists with the same ID.

The main problem is that I'd like to keep using HQL for the queries, and not having to rewrite a new query for this specific purpouse.

What can I do to achieve this result?

Comment: Map the foreign key in your entity as a basic Long mapping as well as with the OneToOne.

Comment: Thank you @Chris, It's not the most elegant solution but thats exactly what I did and it worked.